# Python curses: addstr() from file prints blanks for the remainder of the line

Tags: python, curses, ascii-art

I'm writing a very simple farming game in Python using curses. At this point I have been successful in allowing the player (just a "@" character) to move around within a window.

I have a few files with ascii-art that I print to the window as things to populate the world in which the player can move around. For example, I have a file, named "house", that contains:

```
 _ . ^ . _
/____.____\
|         |
| ## _ ## |
|_""_H_""_|
```

I have a Thing class as follows:

```
class Thing(object):    

    def __init__(self, Xstart, Ystart, looksLike, list, window):
        self.Xstart = Xstart
    self.Ystart = Ystart
    self.X = Xstart
    self.Y = Ystart

    self.looksLike = looksLike

    self.boundries = []
    self.find_boundries()

    list.append(self)

    self.draw(window)


def find_boundries(self):

    file = open(self.looksLike).readlines()
    for line in file:
        for char in line:
        if char == '\n':
            pass
        elif char == ' ':   # skip all whitespace
            self.X += 1
        else:
                self.boundries.append([self.X, self.Y])
            self.X += 1

        self.Y += 1
        self.X = self.Xstart

    self.X = self.Xstart    # reset x & y to starting coordinates
    self.Y = self.Ystart


def draw(self, window):

    #file = open(self.looksLike).readlines()

    #for line in file:
    #    window.addstr(self.Y, self.X, line)
    #    self.Y += 1

#self.Y = self.Ystart

    file = open(self.looksLike).read()

    for char in file:
        window.addch(self.Y, self.X, char)
    if char == '\n':
            self.Y += 1
    self.X = self.Xstart
    else:
    self.X += 1

self.X = self.Xstart    
self.Y = self.Ystart
```

Thus the constructor for my Thing class takes a filename as an argument (looksLike) and the draw method opens the file, reads it, and prints its contents to the window. I can, then, create a house object, pass my "house" file as an argument, and my ascii house will be printed to the window.

The problem is that once the object is printed to the window, when I move the player to the right of the printed object the player disappears. Above, below, and to the left of the printed object, however, the player stays in view. For example,

```
 _ . ^ . _
/____.____\
|         |
| ## _ ## |
|_""_H_""_|
                  @
```

In this position the "@" character is visible, but if I move one space up, it disappears. If I continue moving the player up, the "@" will reappear after it moves beyond the topmost character of the house.

I assume this issue is due to the nature of both addstr() and addch() ( I have tried both) printing whitespace until the end of the window, but I have been unable to find any documentation on this.

I have considered creating a new window for each object printed, but this seems like it would get quite cumbersome when more than a few objects are printed to the window. Also, I hope to define borders around the objects printed to the screen that are shapes other than just squares or rectangles.

Is there anyway to print from a file to the window without the trailing whitespace and without creating a new window for each printed object?

Comment: An http://sscce.org/ might help us help you.

Comment: As a side note, there is no reason to do `file = open(…).readlines()`; the file itself can already be used `for line in file:` without first reading all the lines in and building up a list to use the same way. Also, you're leaking file handles all over the place here, which is not a good idea. Sure, the garbage collector will collect them for you, but why not use a `with` statement? That's what they're there for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume this issue is due to the nature of both addstr() and addch() ( I have tried both) printing whitespace until the end of the window,

Why do you assume that?

First, you never actually call `addstr` in the code you've shown us, so that can't be it.

As for `addch`, it very definitely should not do that—as you could see by just, e.g., drawing from right to left. Or by running this trivial test code:

```
# usual curses setup
stdscr.addch(10, 10, 'a')
stdscr.addch(10, 9, 'b')
```

If you're not seeing the `a` in that test program, there's something wrong with your terminal. But if you are, then your assumption is wrong, and it has nothing to do with `addch`.

---

Almost certainly the problem is that you actually have spaces in the house file. In curses, if you draw a character on top of another character, it replaces the old character, it doesn't try to merge them or overstrike them or anything like that. (Which is good, because most consoles don't have any way to do any such thing…)

If the new character is a space, it just replaces the old character with a space. Exactly like you're seeing.

---

So, the fix is to remove all those spaces on the end of each line, right? Well, you could do that. Or you could just `rstrip()` each line. (You don't need the `\n`; you can tell that you've gotten to the end of a line by the fact that you've finished iterating over the whole line, right? Well, you can in your `file = open(…).readlines()` code, or in code that didn't bother with the `readlines()` and just looped over the file itself; you can't in your different `file = open(…).read()` code, but I don't know why you're doing it differently there in the first place.)

Or, since your `find_boundries` function very carefully skips over spaces, maybe you wanted to do the same thing in `draw` but just forgot to? If so, just write the code you intended to skip over the spaces.

But there's a much simpler solution to the whole problem: Just draw the `@` after the house instead of before it, and this won't even be an issue in the first place. Of course that means that if the player is in the same place as the house, he'll show up "outside" of it rather than being hidden "inside"—but you already appear to have code to prevent that from ever happening, so it shouldn't matter who it *would* look like if it happened.

Comment: The problem is, and I should have mentioned this, that there is not any whitespace after the rightmost characters in the "house" file.

Comment: @user2544396: (a) I'd give 50/50 odds that, despite claiming that, if you actually check what you're reading, there is whitespace. (b) Did you try the simple test I showed to verify that there's nothing wrong with your terminal or your `curses` library? (c) All of the solutions I listed will work even if that _isn't_ the problem; have you tried any of them?

Comment: rstrip() did it! Thanks for the help. I thought there was no whitespace since I hadn't typed any and my cursor in vim wasn't going any farther than the rightmost characters.

Answer (score 1):

Onfortunately I have never used curses, and I cannot see your player class.

Nevertheless maybe this snippet might give you some ideas (press 'x' to exit game) (use WASD to move the player) (requires ANSI-enabled console:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

class _GetchUnix:
    def __init__(self):
        import tty, sys

    def __call__(self):
        import sys, tty, termios
        fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
        old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        try:
            tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
            ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
        finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
        return ch

getch = _GetchUnix ()

house = ''' _ . ^ . _ 
/____.____\\
|         |
| ## _ ## |
|_""_H_""_|'''

class Screen:
    def __init__ (self, width, height, background):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.bg = '\x1b[{}m'.format (40 + background)
        self.clear = '\x1b[0m'
        self.objects = []

    def __iadd__ (self, obj):
        self.objects.append (obj)
        obj.screen = self
        return self

    def render (self):
        print ('\x1b[1;1H', end = '')
        for y in range (self.height):
            for x in range (self.width):
                print (self.bg + ' ' + self.clear, end = '')
            print ()
        for obj in self.objects: obj.render ()
        print ('\x1b[{};1H'.format (self.height) )

class Object:
    def __init__ (self, graphics, foreground, background, x, y):
        self.graphics = graphics.split ('\n')
        self.fg = '\x1b[{}m'.format (30 + foreground)
        self.bg = '\x1b[{}m'.format (40 + background)
        self.clear = '\x1b[0m'
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def render (self):
        for y, line in enumerate (self.graphics):
            print ('\x1b[{};{}H'.format (self.y + y, self.x), end = '')
            print (self.fg + self.bg + line + self.clear)

    def collide (self, x, y):
        if y < self.y: return False
        if x < self.x: return False
        if y > self.y + len (self.graphics) - 1: return False
        if x > self.x + len (self.graphics [y - self.y] ): return False
        return True

    def move (self, dx, dy):
        nx, ny = self.x + dx, self.y + dy
        if ny < 1: return
        if ny > self.screen.height: return
        if nx < 1: return
        if nx > self.screen.width: return
        for obj in self.screen.objects:
            if obj == self: continue
            if obj.collide (nx, ny): return
        self.x, self.y = nx, ny

house = Object (house, 0, 7, 6, 3)
player = Object ('@', 1, 3, 10, 10)
s = Screen (40, 20, 3)
s += house
s += player
while True:
    c = getch ()
    if c == 'x': break
    if c == 'w': player.move (0, -1)
    if c == 's': player.move (0, 1)
    if c == 'a': player.move (-1, 0)
    if c == 'd': player.move (1, 0)
    s.render ()
```

Here a screen shot:

[image]